# facebook not giving email

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing the facebook login using php-facebook sdk. but i am not getting the user's email address from facebook, with newly created applications on facebook.

[image: here is screenshot on the permissions setttings page]

[image: this is preview of auth dialog]

[image: this is actual auth dialog rendering]

as per attached images we have make the changes in permissions settings below for email. when i preview auth dialog, facebook is showing email permission in dialog. but while running the site auth dialog is not showing the email permission and also not giving the email returned.

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I believe you still have to add it to your scope on the website's login button. Depends on your code for that login button, but may be as easy as adding scope="email"

Comment: Could we see some code? Would be nice to see how do you get permissions (and maybe how you get email)

Comment: I added &scope=email,user_birthday in the login url via (Directly and via passing array to facebook sdk), but it did not worked. please see the attached screen shot for more information.

Comment: [**Try this**](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html).
May be help you.

Answer (score 2):

set your scope (permission) in the app settings

also refer this :

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            ));
    $facebookUser = $facebook->getUser();
    $fbLogoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    if ($facebookUser) {
      try {
        $fbUserProfile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
      if (!empty($fbUserProfile)) {
        $fbUserId = $fbUserProfile ['id'];
        $fbUserEmail = $fbUserProfile ['email'];
      }
    } else {
      $fbLoginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload,offline_access'));
      header("Location: " . $fbLoginUrl);
    }
```

Regards : [TechNew.In](http://www.technew.in)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you configure permissions for use with the PHP SDK.

Those settings are for the App Center only (Authenticated Referrals have been removed)

This is one way you can add permissions within the SDK,

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

See more at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/
And: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals